# how can set the different body in WebClient in spring-webflux by a loop?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I'm using spring-webflux and can't set different body generated by the loop

```
public Mono<String> getUsersAndInstrumentOrders(String serviceAddress, String data){
    return webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .uri(serviceAddress)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + HttpWebClient.token)
            .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(data)
            .exchange().log()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                if (clientResponse.rawStatusCode() == 400 || clientResponse.rawStatusCode() == 401) {
                    logger.error("Getting users failed. Error response " + clientResponse.rawStatusCode());
                    return Mono.empty();

                } else {
                    logger.info("Getting users done successfully");
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                }
            }).retry(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("get-users.number-of-retrying")));
}
```

I need to create a loop before this method and generate a different body (data) then save the generated response in a List and give back a list of responses.

Comment: You cant, why? Generate the data, stick it in a flux, onNext for each value emitted do a webclient call, then collectList.

Comment: hi thomas tanks for your reply but I need to use this method generated data for use in input himself method recursive method and return a collection of responses.

Comment: no you don't because you have not written that in your question. If you want a correct answer answer then please supply a correct question. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before this the method I created a recursive method. it generates and emit input (pageNo) to the webClient method (getUsersAndInstrumentOrders). generate page Number until source ApiServive doesn't return the response.

```
public Mono<List<User>> getUsersFromApi(Integer pageNoStart){
    return getUsersAndInstrumentOrders("/api/Report/GetBrokerCustomers",pageNoStart)
            .flatMap(str->{
                com.google.gson.JsonObject jsObj;
                if (str.length()<1){
                    jsObj=new com.google.gson.JsonObject();
                }else {
                    jsObj = JsonParser.parseString(str).getAsJsonObject();
                }
                return Mono.just(jsObj);
            }).flatMap(jsonObj->{
                JsonArray array=jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("resultList");
                for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){
                    JsonObject userJsObject= array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    User user=new User();
                    user.setUsername(userJsObject.get("nationalId").getAsString());
                    user.setMobile(userJsObject.get("mobile").getAsString());
                    user.setIban(userJsObject.get("iban").getAsString());
                    user.setEnabled(true);
                    users.add(user);
                }
                if (array.size()<1) {
                    return Mono.just(users);
                }else {
                    Integer newPageNo=pageNoStart+1;
                    return getUsersFromApi(newPageNo);
                }
            });
}
```

I changed the data input body to fixed data and relative page number to move next page

```
public Mono<String> getUsersAndInstrumentOrders(String serviceAddress, Integer pageNo){
    logger.info("Get getUsersOrInstrumentOrders From Samat");
    return webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .uri(serviceAddress)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + HttpWebClient.token)
            .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue("{\"reportFilter\":{\"orderStatus\":0},\"optionalFilter\":{\"take\":300,\"page\":"+pageNo.toString()+"}}")
            .exchange().log()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                if (clientResponse.rawStatusCode() == 400 || clientResponse.rawStatusCode() == 401) {
                    logger.error("Getting users failed. Error response " + clientResponse.rawStatusCode());
                    return Mono.empty();

                } else {
                    logger.info("Getting users done successfully");
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                }
            }).retry(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("get-users.number-of-retrying")));
}
```